# Returning the value of a key within an object, passed as an argument , what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

The argument 'product' will be an object that looks like this:

```
{ type: 'Easy-peeler satsumas', price: '£1.09', quantity: 8 }
```

Given a 'property' as an argument, return the value associated with that 'property'. 
E.g. if asked for the price 'property' of the above satsumas object, your function would return '£1.09'.

```
function getPropertyOfProduct(product, property) {
let seeIf = Object.values(product[property]);
let tryThis = seeIf.join("");

  return tryThis;
}
```

This returns - `AssertionError: expected '' to equal 8` - yet when I `console.log(tryThis)` it shows £1.09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple,

```js
const myProduct = {type: 'Easy-peeler satsumas', price: '£1.09', quantity: 8};

function getPropertyOfProduct(product, property) {
  return product[property];
}

console.log(getPropertyOfProduct(myProduct, 'price'));
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a really simple solution I think I've just burnt out today! Thank you for your help sorry to waste your time on such a question.

Comment: @CocoFlade Haha no problem, get some rest, the flu is raging :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the requirement correctly then there is no need for this function as one could write `product[property]`. If it must be a function then it could simply be:

```
function getPropertyOfProduct(product, property) {
    return product[property];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a really simple solution I think I've just burnt out today! Thank you for your help sorry to waste your time on such a question.